Query an API only once using spark and replicate response across executors
I am running pyspark over AWS EMR for some data aggregation job. I want to add a column whose value depends on a mapping with another column, that mapping needs to be fetched through a 3rd party API.
I just want to query the API once and use that API response across all executors, so they don't query the API multiple times.
Any ideas on how I can accomplish querying the API only once?
I thought I can run it as a bootstrap action but bootstrap actions are ran on each node, which I would like to avoid and run it only once instead.

Collect all unique values of the "column" on which the mapping depends. Call the API on those unique values. Create a dataframe of those values. Then join with your original dataframe so that these values are available to you.

But won't it give me an API call per unique value per node? i.e if there are are 5 unique values and call the API on them, won't it be 5 X number of nodes? . Since it is running on EMR and I am assuming the code to query the API will be running on all of them at the same time

Nope. Only specific operations are distributed.

You can add your comment as an answer and I can mark it as solved
